# Abstract class and constructor how clr prevents object creation?

Tags: c#, .net

when we check the metadata of abstract class we can see that their is a .ctor method defined in abstract class although its visibilty is protected.
why cant we create the object of abstract base class in derived class even though default constructor is available their?
how c# prevent the object creation?

Comment: Forget `C#` Why do you need to create `instance` of an `abstract` class. To call methods defined in an `abstract` class you can use `base.` in classes extending it.

Comment: `abstract` classes by definition are by design not intended to be instantiatable. Even worse, `protected` constructors are only considered for execution when they are called from children... if your question is limited to the scope of calling the constructor from a child object, then I'll regret my close/down votes on your question.

Comment: +1 : From what I can infer, the question is purely academic. I don't think the question implies that the questioner wants to instantiate an `abstract` class.

Comment: Is this a theoretical design question, or a practical question?

Comment: yes it is theoretical question purely academic

Answer (score 2):

The constructor in the abstract base class is called implictly as part of the contruction process of the derived class.  There's no need to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just because there's a constructor doesn't mean that you can create an instance of it.  Every class (abstract or not) has at least one constructor. Any derived class could call a constructor of the base abstract class within its own constructor.

Comment: static classes do not have one